# Regarding state diagrams - (different levels)

Tags: resource-request, object-oriented-paradigm

UML State diagrams could represent a single object, a system or a sub-system. I am looking for the best methods and resources which help students draw correct state diagrams, and at the right level of detail. Many thanks.

Comment: To what end?  UML can get very detailed and very nitpicky.  What is your goal in teaching UML?

Comment: They have a project where they need to produce a requirement and design documents and they use UML in their documents.

Comment: Do you mean use case diagrams? Or possibly class diagrams?  State diagrams are about capturing a moment of runtime behavior, and aren't, to my knowledge, in frequent use.

Comment: Please see https://www.uml-diagrams.org/state-machine-diagrams.html.  They show state of objects or sub-systems.

Comment: State diagrams got in to UML, because the company that made a good state modelling tool, had a seat on the UML board. There is also much left out of UML.